# Vertically centering button using css

Tags: html, css, layout

I am trying to make a simple input button center-align within a table cell.

My markup is:

```html
<table width="500" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td width="390">XXXXXXXXX</td>
    <td width="110" rowspan="2" valign="middle"><input type="button" value="submit"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>YYYYYYYY</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br /><br />
<div style="width:500px;">
  <div style="float:left;width:390px;">
    <div>XXXXXXX</div>
    <div>YYYYYYY</div>
  </div>
  <div style="vertical-align:middle;width:110px;float:right;">
    <div><input type="button" value="submit"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have done a table version showing you the layout that I am trying to achieve.  Note that the text represented by "XXXXX" or "YYYYYY" is of variable length.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/8v8gLn4y/

```css
.container {
  background: lightblue;
  display: table;
  width:100%;
}
        
input[type=button] {    
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
        
.button-wrapper {
  background: darkorange;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
    
  <div>some line with text</div>
  <div>another line with text</div>    
    
  <div class='button-wrapper'>
    <input type="button" value="submit"  />
  </div>
    
</div>
```

*update 2016*:
flexbox

```css
.container {
  background: bisque;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.container>div {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.button-wrapper {
  background: chocolate;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

input[type=button] {
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  flex-shrink: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>

  <div>
    <p>some line with text</p>
    <p>another line with text</p>
  </div>

  <div class='button-wrapper'>
    <input type="button" value="submit" />
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the help, it's been driving me crazy. Your solution works perfectly. :)

Comment: if I change <input type="button" /> to <button> it will work not correct. Can you help me to use with <button> ?

Comment: @Hoang you would have to change this line in the html `<input type="button" value="submit"  />` to `<button>click me</button>`

Answer (score -2):

If you make your button an `inline` element and add `text-align: center` to the parent `td` you should be fine.

```css
.tools {
  text-align: center;
}

.submit {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<table width="500" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td width="390">XXXXXXXXX</td>
    <td class="tools" width="110" rowspan="2" valign="middle"><input class- "submit" type="button" value="submit"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>YYYYYYYY</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br /><br />
<div style="width:500px;">
  <div style="float:left;width:390px;">
    <div>XXXXXXX</div>
    <div>YYYYYYY</div>
  </div>
  <div style="vertical-align:middle;width:110px;float:right;">
    <div><input type="button" value="submit"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: OP wanted a solution NOT using a table