# How to center my buttons vertically?

Tags: html, css, button

I put a div around each button and I set them both to inline. They just want to stack as I keep trying to center them.

This is my HTML:

```css
     body{
  background-color:black;
     }


    #light{
 margin-left:50%;
 margin-right:70%;
    }

    #dark{
 margin-left:50%;
 margin-right:50%;
 display:inline-block;
    }
 

    h3{
 color:white;
 font-family:Courier New;
 font-size:24px;
 margin-left:500px;
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>question reality.</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="intro page.css">
    </head>

    <body>

    <h3>make your choice.</h3>

    <div id="light"><button>Light</button></div>
    <div id="dark"><button>Dark</button></div>


    </body>
    </html>
```

This is a screencap of what this thing is doing:

[image]

Comment: use text-align:center property instead of margin left and right and give a try

Comment: Pls refer to this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396145/how-to-vertically-center-a-div-for-all-browsers . It has a better way of dealing with this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to vertically center a div for all browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396145/how-to-vertically-center-a-div-for-all-browsers)

Comment: I don't think it is a good practice to have space in file names as you did for your css file: `href="intro page.css"`

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to set the `#light` div to `inline-block`.  But probably a better way to do it is just to surround both buttons in a div and give that some css of `text-align:center` like so:

```css
body{
  background:black;
}
h3{
  text-align:center;
  color:white;
  font-family:Courier New;
  font-size:24px;
}
.text-center{
    text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<h3>Make Your Choice</h3>
<div class="text-center">
    <button>Light</button>
    <button>Dark</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

CSS

```
 body{
 background-color:black;
 }


#light,#dark,h3{
  text-align:center;
}


h3{
color:white;
font-family:Courier New;
font-size:24px;
}
```

use text-align:center property instead of margins on left and right

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

Hope this would help:

```css
body{
    background-color:black;
}
#light{
    position: absolute;
    top: 45%;
    left: 50%;
}
#dark{
    position: absolute;
    top: 55%;
    left: 50%;
}
h3{
    color:white;
    font-family:Courier New;
    font-size:24px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>question reality.</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="intro page.css">
  </head>

  <body>

    <h3>make your choice.</h3>

    <div id="light"><button>Light</button></div>
    <div id="dark"><button>Dark</button></div>


  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Place your buttons in  a main container div, 100% width, and change the margins of the buttons to auto. The parent div must be 100% width and the children, will center align if their margin is set to auto.
https://codepen.io/DannaB67/pen/KqRoJK

```
   body{
     background-color:black;
     }
  .main{
    width:100%;}

  #light{
    margin:auto;
    display:inline-block;
    }

  #dark{
    margin:auto;
    display:inline-block;
    }

  h3{
    color:white;
    font-family:Courier New;
    font-size:24px;
    text-align: center;
    }

<body>

    <div align="center" class="main">

      <h3>make your choice.</h3>
      <div id="light"><button>Light</button></div>
      <div id="dark"><button>Dark</button></div>

   </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try two things

1. Use following styling and remove unnecessary margin-right

   ```
   button {     
      margin-top : __px;
   }
   ```

   2. Use position relative

      ```
      button {
         position: relative;
         top:20%;
      }
      ```

This will solve your problem

OR you can also try first answer at [Vertically centering button using css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8786583/vertically-centering-button-using-css)

Let me know if you require any further help