# how do I vertically center a button element with an image inside a form?

Tags: html, css, forms

I am building user interface for responsive single page chat application using `HTML` and `CSS`. The interface must include a `<form>` element for submitting a message.
Inside the `<form>` element I have `<textarea>` element and `<button>` element as submit button. The button must have inside it two images one centered on the other, and after a lot of effort and searchs I managed to do that. The problem is that I want this `<button>` and `<textarea>` to be on the same line and vertically centered in the `<form>`. I tried and searched a lot for something that may help me but none of the results was what I need,some of the what I tried is based on the answers in the following link:

[Vertically centering button using css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8786583/vertically-centering-button-using-css)

see my code in [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5h8c3zt3/1/).

Note: I am not allowed using CSS frameworks and no IDs for styling.

I appreciate any help.
Thank you!

Comment: Is this the desired effect? https://jsfiddle.net/MattDiMu/aj363t4b/

Comment: what you are trying to do ? create an image what you trying to achieve

Comment: unfortunately no

Comment: @Jishnu V S I want to vertically center the button in the form

Comment: Flexbox is what you need.

Comment: @giorgio thank you and for all who tried to help me , but why did my question got a minus? what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

use `vertical-align:middle;` on `textarea`

CSS

```
textarea{
vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Comment: I tried but then the button goes to the top of the form

Comment: what is the image size you placed inside the button?

Comment: the background is 100% and the one inside is  width: 45.0704%;
  height: 22.831%;

Comment: @sherenelias can you post a image about the issue you are facing

Answer (score -1):

You can adjust your image by giving it width, height and required margin padding.

```
img {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

For centering objects you can use margin: 0 auto;